# Dynamically change CSS flex order via JavaScript based on user event order

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an application that has a `<nav>` selection list of items that will dynamically open in an `<article>` area.  Each item is defined as a `<div>` in the `<article>` area with `display:none`, until each is activated by a JavaScript function as the user clicks selections in the `<nav>`.  As they appear in the `<article>` area, they show up in the sequence they are defined in the `<article>`.  The salient and somewhat pseudo parts of the code are shown below.

I would like each div to show up in the sequence that the user clicks, and not in the sequence the divs are laid out.  So if the user selects `item002` then `item001`, the respective divs would show in the sequence `item002, item001`.

I've been trying to find a way to do this with flex column layout by dynamically changing the order of the article divs, something like:

```
document.getElementById(shID).order = myOrdervar;
```

So far nothing I've tried has worked, and I can't find documentation on flex telling me if this is even possible.  Does anyone have a technique for changing the display sequence of the article divs, with or without flex?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 1em Helvetica;
            background: #999999;
        }
        #main {
            min-height: 500px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
        }
        #main > article {
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #cccc33;
            border-radius: 7pt;
            background: #dddd88;
            height: 600px;
            flex: 3 1 60%;
            order: 2;
            flex-flow: column;
        }
        #main > nav {
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #8888bb;
            border-radius: 7pt;
            background: #ccccff;
            height: 600px;
            flex: 1 6 20%;
            order: 1;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        header, footer {
            display: block;
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 5px;
            min-height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #eebb55;
            border-radius: 7pt;
            background: #ffeebb;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        /* Too narrow to support three columns */
        @media all and (max-width: 640px) {
            #main, #page {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            #main > article, #main > nav, #main > aside {
                /* Return them to document order */
                order: 0;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            #main > nav, #main > aside, header, footer {
                min-height: 50px;
                max-height: 50px;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var globalOrder = 1;
        function showHide(shID) {
            if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
                if (document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
                    document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'flex';
                    document.getElementById(shID).style.order = globalOrder;
                    globalOrder++;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'inline';
                    document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
        .more {
            display: none;
            border-top: 0px solid #666;
            border-bottom: 0px solid #666;
        }
        .showSquid {
            display: block;
            border-top: 0px solid #666;
            border-bottom: 0px solid #666;
        }
        a.showLink, a.hideLink {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            font-family: 'MergeLight', Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-left: 0px;
            border-top: 0px solid #666;
            border-bottom: 0px dotted #36f;
        }
        a.hideLink {
            background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left;
        }
        a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Sources
    </header>
    <div id='main'>
        <nav>
            <a href='#' id='Wilmington Wind-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide("Wilmington Wind");return false;'>
                Wilmington Wind
            </a><br>
            <a href='#' id='ArtMachine.mp3-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide("ArtMachine.mp3");return false;'>
                Art Machine
            </a><br>
            <a href='#' id='Breathing-original.mp3-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide("Breathing-original.mp3");return false;'>
                Breathing
            </a><br>
            <a href='#' id='ToroidMachine-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide("ToroidMachine");return false;'>
            </a>
        </nav>
        <article>
            <div id='Wilmington Wind' class='more' style="flex-direction: column;">
                Wilmington Wind<br>
            </div>
            <div id='ArtMachine.mp3' class='more' style="flex-direction: column;">
                Art Machine<br>
            </div>
            <div id='Breathing-original.mp3' class='more' style="flex-direction: column;">
                Breathing
            </div> <!-- Breathing-original.mp3 -->
        </article>
        <footer>&copy; 2017</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not much we can do when there is no working code snippet reproducing the issue, and of course you can change `order` using javascript. Optionally you can swap element position in the markup with script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent element needs `display: flex;` — in your case, that's the `<article>` element.

Add this in your `<style>` element:

```
article {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much aaron, I had a feeling that I was missing a flex reference, but I couldn't see where to define it.  That did the trick, it's working exactly as I had hoped!

Answer (score 2):

You miss the `.style` part in `document.getElementById(shID).order=myOrdervar;`:

```
document.getElementById(shID).style.order=myOrdervar;
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed that which explained one of the problems I was having with my various tests.  Unfortunately it's not re-sequencing the divs, they're still showing up in the order they're laid out in the <article> section.

Comment: I updated the code above to give a simple example of the actual page I'm working on.  Regardless of how I try to set order I can't change the sequence of the divs that open in the article area.  I must be doing something stupid, but I can't see it...

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, I wrote that

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.questions {
    /* width: 600px; */
    max-width: 600px;
}

.question {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.question-label {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.propositions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.proposition {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    /* transition: 2s ease; */
    /* transition-duration: 2s; */
}

.proposition-label {
    padding: 1em;
    /* background: yellow; */
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.proposition-buttons {
    padding: 1em;
    /* background: red; */
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.propositions .p1 {
    background: green;
    order: 1;
}

.propositions .p2 {
    background: yellow;
    order: 2;
}

.propositions .p3 {
    background: aqua;
    order: 3;
}

.propositions .p4 {
    background: gray;
    order: 4;
}


.question .legend {
    font-size: .8em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

a.proposition-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    /*width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;*/
    padding: .25em;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

a.proposition-btn:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
    <link href="assets/fontawesome-6.4.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script>
        const reps = [];
        
        //
        function updateOrder(questionNum, propositionNum, nextOrder) {
            for(i = 0; i < nextOrder.length; i++) {
                const value = nextOrder[i];
                const idProposition = 'q' + questionNum + '_p' + value;
                const divProposition = document.getElementById(idProposition);
                divProposition.style.order = i + 1;
            }

            // input
            const inputId = 'rep' + questionNum;
            const input = document.getElementById(inputId);
            const nextValue = nextOrder.join('-');
            input.value = nextValue;
        }

        // 
        function down(questionNum, propositionNum) {
            const order = reps[questionNum];        
            const pos = order.indexOf(propositionNum);

            if(pos == 3) {
                console.log('Deja en bas');
                return;
            }

            const nextOrder = [];
            for(i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
                nextOrder.push(order[i]);
            }
            nextOrder.push(order[pos + 1]);
            nextOrder.push(propositionNum);
            
            
            for(i = pos + 2; i < order.length; i++) {
                nextOrder.push(order[i]);
            }

            reps[questionNum] = nextOrder;

            updateOrder(questionNum, propositionNum, nextOrder);
        }


        // 
        function up(questionNum, propositionNum) {
            const order = reps[questionNum];        
            const pos = order.indexOf(propositionNum);
        
            if(pos == 0) {
                console.log('Deja en gaut');
                return;
            }
        
            const nextOrder = [];
            for(i = 0; i < pos -1; i++) {
                nextOrder.push(order[i]);
            }
            nextOrder.push(propositionNum);
            nextOrder.push(order[pos - 1]);
            
            for(i = pos + 1; i < order.length; i++) {
                nextOrder.push(order[i]);
            }
        
            reps[questionNum] = nextOrder;

            updateOrder(questionNum, propositionNum, nextOrder);
        }
        </script>



    </head>
    <body>




        <div class="questions">

            <input type="hidden" name="rep1" id="rep1" value="1-2-3-4" />
            <script>
                reps[1] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            </script>
            <div class="question" id="q1">
                <div class="question-label">
                    1. Quel est votre jour préféré ?
                </div>
                <div class="propositions">
                    <div class="proposition p1" id="q1_p1">
                        <div class="proposition-label">
                            Lundi
                        </div>
                        <div class="proposition-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="down(1, 1)">Down</a>
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="up(1, 1)">Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="proposition p2" id="q1_p2">
                        <div class="proposition-label">
                            Mardi
                        </div>
                        <div class="proposition-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="down(1, 2)">Down</a>
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="up(1, 2)">Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="proposition p3" id="q1_p3">
                        <div class="proposition-label">
                            Mercredi
                        </div>
                        <div class="proposition-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="down(1, 3)">Down</a>
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="up(1, 3)">Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="proposition p4" id="q1_p4">
                        <div class="proposition-label">
                            Jeudi
                        </div>
                        <div class="proposition-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="down(1, 4)">Down</a>
                            <a href="#" class="proposition-btn" onclick="up(1, 4)">Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend">
                    Classez les propositions à l'aide des flèches (en haut celle qui vous correspond le plus).
                </div>
            </div>






    </div>


    

    </body>

</html>
```